# Размер файла получившийся после сборки слишком большой webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

При сборке `js` и `css` получаю ошибку.
Конечный `CSS` файл получается слишком **большим (438кб)**, по сравнению с изначальным **(16кб)**

Вот  прежупреждения которое после сборки появляется

> WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the
>   recommended size limit (250 kB). This can impact web performance.
>   Assets:   style.css (448 kB)
>
> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined
>   asset size exceeds the recommended limit (250 kB). This can impact web
>   performance. Entrypoints:   main (456 kB)
>         bundle.js
>         style.css
>
> WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: You can limit the size
>   of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some
>   parts of your application. For more info visit
>   https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Содержимое файла **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const webpack = require("webpack");

const config = {
    entry: "./common.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename:"bundle.js"
    },
    // performance: {
    //  maxEntrypointSize:400000
    // },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use:"babel-loader",
                test: /\.js$/,
            },
            {
                loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader:"css-loader"
                    // options: {minimize:true}
                }),
                test: /\.css$/,

            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:"url-loader"
                        // options:{ limit:40000 }
                    },
                    "image-webpack-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
    ]
};
if (NODE_ENV == "production") {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress:{
                warnings:false,
                drop_console:true,
                unsafe:true
            }
        })
    );
}
module.exports = config;
```

`style.css` содержит 900 строк кода. Ниже приведено несколько строк:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    font-family:  Helvetica , Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    padding: 0 0 60px;
}

.background-img {
    background-image: url("../img/office.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможно какие-то импорт из node_modules идёт? Неплохо было бы увидеть Ваш css.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко да шас покажу свой css

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко из node_modules ничего не идет

Comment: похоже что `loader:"url-loader"` превращяет `background-image: url("../img/office.jpg");` в DataUrl и записывает ее прято в css файл. Попробуйте проверить это в инспекторе кода, проинспектировав `.background-img`.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко да вы были правы получается длинный файл внутри background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4Q имя слишком длинный я обрезал его и поставил суда всего треть часть его имени

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко проверил в инспекторе кода но как решить данную задачу чтобы не превращал background-image в DataUrl?

Comment: Я думаю есть как минимум есть 3 варианта решения(1 у Вас в коде закомментирован):

Comment: 1. Установить лимит на отработку файлов в `options:{ limit:40000 }`
2. Вместо модуля `test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,` воспользоваться плагином https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-tinypng-compress
3. Удалить модуль `test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,` из вебпака и воспользоваться чем-то другим. Я для своих проектов так и делаю: для продовой сборки картинок и шрифов использую Gulp.

Comment: Еще думаю можно посмотреть на этот модуль: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко спасибо за вариант решений но когда я убераю комментарий получаю ошибку.Ну постараюсь решить самостаятельно спасибо вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что `loader:"url-loader"` превращяет background-image: `url("../img/office.jpg");` в DataUrl и записывает ее прято в css файл. Попробуйте проверить это в инспекторе кода, проинспектировав `.background-img`